# Attacking both authenticity and secrecy in authenticated encryption modes

Tags: aes, symmetric, mac, authenticated-encryption, gcm

looks like NIST only approved GCM mode for authenticated encryption and other modes don't have any approval or a good implementation available.

- Is that possible a weakness in $GHASH$ compromise plain-text or it just allow attacker to forge it? can we use AES-GCM with confidence or is better to use a confidential only mode for encryption and HMAC cipher-text with same key to protect plain-text in long terms?
- How strong is GCM authentication compared to HMAC-SHA256? what is poly time to forge plain-text?
- Where attacker can practically forge plain-text in real life? adding malicious codes to software downloads? what if plain-text is padded? can he identify and change chat messages? where else?

Comment: Probably not relevant (and he notes that you *shouldn't* try to use his implementation for your own purposes), but AGL has recently implemented ChaCha/Salsa into Chrome: [ [link](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/27/tlssymmetriccrypto.html) ]

Comment: @figlesquidge why in that blog post he says "Chrome talking to Google uses AES-GCM if there's hardware support at the client" ? what is hardware support mean ?

Comment: Aes-gcm is very quick IF the critical calculations can be done in hardware. However, in software a secure implementation is slower than a secure implementation of cha cha/salsa

Comment: @figlesquidge what hardware client may have to do that? on server it make sense but in client side we don't have usually custom crypto chips...?

Comment: Modern Intel chips contain special instructions for efficiently calculating aes or certain finite field products, making aes-gcm very quick.  There's a paper about it, but I can't give you a link because I'm on my phone

Comment: On x86/AMD64 CPUs "hardware support" means that the AES-NI instruction set is supported, which contains special instructions for AES and GCM (the latter can be used for binary field operation in general).

Answer (score 1):

1. AES-GCM encrypts the plaintext in the [Counter Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29). GHASH operates on the resulting ciphertext, so no weakness in GHASH could compromise the confidentiality of plaintext.
2. The GCM authentication is not as strong as that of SHA-256, in particular on short tags. If the tag is $\tau$-bit, an adversary can forge the tag after $2^{\tau/2}$ attempts given the encryption of a message $2^{\tau/2}$ block long. For 32-bit tags this implies $2^{16}$-block long single message and $2^{16}$ forgery attempts at short messages. For HMAC-SHA256 the corresponding values are $2^{32}$, or $2^{\tau}$ in general case.

Comment: GHASH use same key we used to encrypt plain-text. if GHASH compromise how encryption key survive as its same thing we used in GHASH ?